# Need help troubleshooting 'KeyError: None of [Index([] are in the [index]' error in Python linear regression with Ridge regularization

Tags: python, linear-regression

I found error in regularization:

**input:** x_train.columns

**output:** Index(['Year', 'Life_expectancy', 'Adult_Mortality', 'infant_deaths',
'Alcohol', 'percentage_expenditure', 'Hepatitis_B', 'Measles', 'BMI',
'under_five_deaths', 'Polio', 'Total_expenditure', 'Diphtheria',
'HIV_or_AIDS', 'GDP', 'Population', 'thinness_1_19_years',
'thinness_5_9_years', 'Income_composition_of_resources', 'Schooling'],
dtype='object')

**input:** Regularization code

[image]

here's the error:

[image]

```
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x_train[features])
y = x_train[label]

X_test = StandardScaler().fit_transform(y_test[features])
y_test_1 = y_test[label]

for myalpha in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1, 1.5, 2]:
# for myalpha in [0.01, 0.05, 0.1]:
  ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha=myalpha)
  ridge_reg.fit(X,y)

  ## Model's training error
  y_pred = ridge_reg.predict(X)
  residuals = y - y_pred
  MSE = np.mean(residuals**2)
  RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE)
  MAE = np.mean(abs(residuals))

  ## Model's test set error
  y_test_pred = ridge_reg.predict(X_test)
  residuals = y_test_1 - y_test_pred
  MSE = np.mean(residuals**2)
  RMSE_test = np.sqrt(MSE)

  # print('MSE:',MSE)
  print('alpha:', myalpha,', RMSE train:', RMSE, ', RMSE test:',
RMSE_test)
  # print('MAE:',MAE)
```

Comment: Please provide your code in the post as text, not as an image.

Comment: yes, i just provided the code